# Is it possible to select/filter subnets based on subnets' tag value in AWS CDK V2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, subnet

currently I have one VPC in my account, and there're a bunch of subnets inside it already existed, and different subnets have different tags.

And I am trying to use AWS CDK to select/filter out the some already existed subnets with the right tag/value pair? is there a way to achieve this?

given the VPC and tag values, to return the corresponding subnets in AWS CDK.

I've looked into the AWS CDK api reference, but failed to find the function I need.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for this as well, and as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this at the time of writing (July 2023). The reason is probably that the underlying CloudFormation code doesn't support it.

I prefer not hard-code the values, and I prefer not to use the AWS SDK to look up values inside CDK stacks, so my solution was to put the subnet ids in an SSM variable, and then extract them later in my CDK stacks with [`StringListParameter.from*`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringListParameter.html).

I don't control the network stack in my environment, but if you do, you can also add the ids as stack outputs from the network stack, and import them later.